# Emulator creates adb.exe copies

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

Env: Win 7, Android Studio(3.0.1), Java 8 
When i start emulator via Android Studio the emulator creates new threads of adb.exe. Afer closing the Emulator, the adb Threads Persist.
[screenshot of TaskManager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Jxhu.png)
I tried different Tablets and Phones and dont have this kind of problem with real devices.

Answer (score 1):

I am having the exact same issue with Win 7, AS(3.0.1) and Java 8.  The number of adb.exe instances continually grow and grow throughout the day to the point where I am running at 90% or more RAM and my PC is not longer operable without a reboot.

My work around at the moment was to create a .bat file with the following command and run it periodically throughout the day.

```
taskkill /F /IM adb.exe /T
```

It may not be ideal as it kills whatever instance of the emulator I have running, but at least I can avoid a reboot.

**EDIT:**
It has been an hour and I am around 1500 instances and counting. See my
 [Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMhtf.png)

Comment: Thats what i do too. I have it runing in a loop every 5 minutes.

Comment: Still a problem on Android Studio 3.1.3 it seems.

Answer (score 0):

I thought this could be linked to my version of ADB, so I downgraded it to 26.0.2, but it didn't change anything.
It has to be linked to Android Studio (tried 3.0.1 and 3.2 Canary 2) or the SDK tools.